# How to keep scrollbar at the top of a modal popup

Tags: css, blazor

I'm used Blazor to make a modal popup but I've noticed that the scrollbar automatically jumps to the bottom of the popup versus being at the top when the modal is opened. I used the basic overflow:auto in my css class and I tried using transform:rotateX(180deg) which does flip the scrollbar to the top of the modal, but also flips the text upside down. Is there a way to get the scrollbar to the top of the modal using only Css without flipping the text?

Comment: Why don't you use overflow:hidden ? Do you need the scrollbar ?

Comment: I do need the scrollbar so that the user can scroll through and see the different fields to fill in

Comment: My issue is that when the button is clicked and the modal pops up the user is taken straight to the bottom of the modal and has to scroll up to see the other fields in the modal which is not ideal from a UX standpoint

Comment: Try the following: Add a div element to the top of your modal, and in JInterop  do something like this: var topPage = document.getElementById("#top-page");

window.onload = () => window.scrollTo({ top: 0, behavior: 'smooth' });